# How to sort by numbers that are part of a filename in bash?

Tags: bash, sorting, grep, ls

I'm trying to assign a variable in bash to the file in this directory with the largest number before the '.tar.gz' and I'm drawing a complete blank on the best way to approach this:

```
ls /dirname | sort   
daily-500-12345.tar.gz  
daily-500-12345678.tar.gz  
daily-500-987654321.tar.gz  
weekly-200-1111111.tar.gz  
monthly-100-8675309.tar.gz
```

Comment: Use the `-v` option to do a natural sort.

Answer (score 6):

```
sort -Vrt - -k3,3
```

- `-V` Natural sort
- `-r` Reverse, so you can use `head -1` to get the first line only
- `-t -` Use hyphen as field separator
- `-k3,3` Sort using only the third field

Output:

```
daily-500-987654321.tar.gz
daily-500-12345678.tar.gz
monthly-100-8675309.tar.gz
weekly-200-1111111.tar.gz
daily-500-12345.tar.gz
```